# make private folder

Tags: android, security, file, directory, private

When my application starts,
 I am creating one folder/directory and writing one file into it
Now what I want is, 
only my application can access this folder , no other can access this
Is it possible in Android or Not
Please can some one tell me

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

for that you need to make that folder in application's internal memory, so that no one can access that folder .

```
private File cacheDir = null;
cacheDir = new File(getCacheDir(),"your folder name");
if (!cacheDir.exists())
    cacheDir.mkdirs();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply,
I need one more help,
Suppose, I am installing my application in SD Card,
What if my content are photos and some other large files then.?,
is it fine above method, still can I hide content of that folder from others..?

Comment: No you can not hide those files which are stored on SDcard